# Prove that it is impossible that there exists $a,b,c\in G$ such that $a\neq b$ but $a\circ c = b\circ c$.

Tags: group-theory

Prove that it is impossible that there exists $a,b,c\in G$ such that $a\neq b$ but $a\circ c = b\circ c$.

How would I do this without starting with the assumption that a = b? I looked around and I can't quite find a way to start this.

Comment: As a hint - $c^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: But you may start with the assumption that $a\circ c = b\circ c$.

Comment: Prove that if $a \circ c = b \circ c$, then $a=b$. Also, you forgot to say that $(G,\circ)$ is a group.

Comment: yes, usually the little circle is used for function composition.

Comment: Assume: a\neq b

then I apply the inverse of c to both sides and arrive at the equality nonetheless, thus a must equal b.

Would that be a sound proof? 

Sorry for omitting G being a group.

Comment: You must say "I $\color{red}{\text{right}}$-multiply by $c^{-1}$.